# Использование параметра класса в теле класса

Tags: python, классы, переменные, атрибуты

Есть класс, который принимает параметр. Проблема возникает при попытке использования этого параметра в теле класса (не в функции), как на примере ниже. Какие существуют способы реализации представленного ниже функционала. Спасибо.

```
class Test:

    def __init__(self, var):
        self.var = var
    

    new_var = 10 * self.var  # Не работает
    
    if self.var:
        other_var = self.var / 2  # Не работает
```

Comment: Это проблема xy, напишите, зачем вам это нужно, т.е. какую проблему вы пытаетесь решить.

Answer (score 2):

Класс ничего не знает об экземплярах класса, вы должны каким-то образом передавать информацию из создаваемых экземпляров в основной класс. Ну, вернее, можно исхитриться при желании, и найти например в глобальных переменных все экземпляры данного класса, но это выглядит не очень прямо.

В общем, учитывая вышесказанное, можно сделать примерно так:

```py
class Test:

    def __init__(self, var):
        self.var = var
    
        Test.new_var = 10 * self.var
    
        if self.var:
            Test.other_var = self.var / 2

t = Test(42)
del t 
# экземпляра больше нет, но он уже передал классу нужную информацию
print(Test.new_var)
print(Test.other_var)
# 420
# 21.0
```

Comment: что-то не то в конце - 42 там, а не 21:-)

Comment: @Сергей Это я вместе с не нужным теперь комментарием и хвост кода отрезал случайно, спасибо )

Comment: А если нам нужно, чтобы переменная **var** оказывала влияние именно на экземпляры класса, то это будет выглядеть также или как то иначе? Т.е.

`t = Test(42)
t2 = Test(20)

print(t.new_var)  # 420
print(t.other_var)  # 21.0
print(t2.new_var)  # 200
print(t2.other_var)  # 10.0`

Comment: @KraKra Если вы хотите, чтобы переменная у каждого класса была своя, то просто используйте `self.var` Сформулируйте чётко - что вы хотите? Переменные класса будут одинаковые у всех экземпляров, а переменные экземпляра будут разные у всех.

Comment: Да, извиняюсь если сформулировал не совсем корректно. Однако на один вопрос получил ответ сразу на два кейса) Спасибо, @CrazyElf